# как забрать данные из span

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4, lxml

```
<span class="price-text-E1Y7h text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL">34 790<!-- --> <span class="price-currency-_B87m">₽</span></span>
```

Парсил авито , хотел вытащить ценник [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
answer = soup.find('span', class_="price-text-E1Y7h")
   print(answer['text'])
```

забрать по ключу text не получилось выдаёт исключение KeyError

знаю что можно вырезать всё лишнее методом strip но думаю что есть способ лаконичней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer.text вытащил нужный мне текст